# Get only part of a file in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

Couldn't find anything about this on the internet, or stackoverflow?!?

### Basic Example:

A great example of what I want to know is, how would you create an if statement that returns true if it finds a word or phrase **in a sentence**.

### Another Example:

Let's say we have an IP blocklist in an external file. So I presume we'll need to use `file_get_contents` somewhere in the if statement.

```
// IP Blocklist
118.92.00
119.92.11
125.23.10
```

Ok so that's our example IP blocklist. How would you create an if statement that is able to find the middle IP (119.92.11), even though there is other content there (keeping in mind it could very well change!)?

Comment: [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) is all you need - `if (strpos($subjectString, $searchString) !== FALSE) { // substring exists }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two examples would require two different techniques to be reliable.

Example 1 simply requires [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
if (strpos($subjectString, $searchString) !== FALSE) {
  // substring exists
} else {
  // substring doesn't exist
}
```

You could use `stripos()` instead if you want to match in a case-insensitive manner.

For example two it would be better to use an array. This is because the `strpos()` approach would match `11.22.22.11` if `11.22.22.110` was in the array - and you don't want this.

Instead, you would do something like this, using [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
// Get a list of IPs from file and split into an array
$ips = preg_split('/\s+/', trim(file_get_contents('list-of-ips.txt')));

if (in_array($searchIP, $ips)) {
  // IP exists
} else {
  // IP doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Hey Dave. Great answer :). A quick question though, if that's okay: how does the second example find a certain IP in that `list-of-ips.txt`??

Comment: The code assumes that you have assigned the IP you are looking for to `$searchIP`. So you are checking if the value in `$searchIP` exists in the array `$ips`, which the first line creates from the contents of the file.

Comment: Perfect. Great answer couldn't have asked for better. Thanks so much mate :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strpos($file_contents, "119.92.11") !== false)
{
  //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: You need to use `!==` or this will give a false negative when "119.92.11" is at position 0 (beginning of the file).

Comment: Also, I would not `strpos()` the entire file contents, but line-by-line instead.  What happens if an IP like "24.119.92.11" is in the block list?  It will give another false positive, because the OP is looking for "119.92.11.*" presumably.  It will also give false positives for addresses like "119.92.111", "119.92.115", and so on.  It may be better to use a regular expression in this case.  Sorry, I don't mean to pick on you. :-)

Comment: ye, you should now right the exact same comment to all other answer that used the exact same concept given as an EXAMPLE on how to use strpos not do the actual work for him.

Answer (score 0):

This is for external file

```
$ips = file ( $file );
$searchIP = "119.92.11";
$found = false;
foreach ( $ips as $ip ) {
    if ($ip == $searchIP) {
        $found = true;
    }
}

if ($found) {
    echo $searchIP, " Found";
}
```

Comment: Perfect as always Baba :). To be honest though, this method doesn't seem as clean as the strpos method others are suggesting. Which method do you think would be best?

Comment: You question request is completely 2 different things .. i would `strpos` for string but not for files nope ... files might have so many things you would like to customize .. for every large file both method would fail only `fopen` would be most effective .. as i said .. it depends on your use use case

Comment: Ahh okay. Well at most the file I want to target would have no more than 2 different urls in it, so it's not like it will be large?

Comment: Just give a full description what exactly you want to do and store i would tell you the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Just use the strpos function.

> The strpos() function returns the position of the first occurrence of
>   a string inside another string.
>
> If the string is not found, this function returns FALSE.

For example:

```
$ipAddresses = '// IP Blocklist
118.92.00
119.92.11
125.23.10';

if (strpos($ipAddresses,"119.92.11") != FALSE) {
    // IP ADDRESS WAS FOUND
} else {
    // IP ADDRESS NOT FOUND
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression for accuracy and flexibility:

```
$lines = file($blockListFile);
$findIp = '119.92.11';

$findIp = trim($findIp, '.');

// The number of unspecified IP classes (e.g. for "192.92.11", it would be 1,
// but for "192.92" it would be 2, and so on).
$n = 4 - (substr_count($findIp, '.') + 1)

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/^' . preg_quote($findIp, '/') . '(\.\d{1,3}){0,' . $n . '}$/', $line)) {
        // the line matches the search address
    } else {
        // the line does not match the search address
    }
}
```

This method allows searching for any number of IP classes (e.g. "192.92.11.45", "192.92.11", "192.92", or even just "192").  It will always match at the beginning of the line, so that, for example, searching for "192.92.11" will not match "24.192.92.11".  It also only matches full classes, so that searching for "192.92.11" will not match "192.92.115" or "192.92.117.21".

**Edit:**

Please note that this solution assumes:

- Your search term is specified in full classes (e.g. searching for "192.92.11" means you want to match `/^192.92.11(\.\d{1,3})?$/`)
- The IPs specified in your block list file are also specified in full classes